# Writing generic/native look GUI linux application

Tags: linux, qt, gtk, gnome, kde-plasma

Is there a way to create Linux application that will have native/generic look and feel on all DEs? For example if I wrote app in GTK it will look fine/native on Gnome, but on KDE (QT) it can look ugly. I'm wonder is there a generic framework for creating UI (best if have declarative syntax for UI) independent from DE, that will create native look and feel on all DEs?

Comment: What kind of Linux application have you in mind? Please edit your question to be more specific and explain what you want it to do...

Comment: Why do you ask? Don't you think that the functionality of your application is much more important than its appearance and look&feel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, because I am not sure that any *native look* is *well* defined. However, toolkits like GTK (used by Gnome & XFCE) and Qt (used by KDE) are somehow standardizing some "common" (or at least usual) look... (and indeed, both Gnome and KDE define some visual and behavior guides, which are incompatible).

Did you consider making a web application -perhaps using FastCGI, or even some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)? It would use the usual browser "look and feel" ...

Notice that thanks to [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and *conventions* like [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html),  applications written in GTK can inter-operate with applications written in Qt (and vice-versa), even if they are looking slightly different... And as commented by [andlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3408572/andlabs), you might make appropriate themes for them to make them look even more similar.

Also, several Unix and Linux applications (even recent ones like [git](https://git-scm.com/)) are mostly [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) applications (which does the bulk of the work), with some smaller GUI wrappers, perhaps communicating with the CLI application (e.g. thru pipes). Perhaps you could organize your application likewise: have most of the work done by some *command line executable* and add some *small*
 GUI wrappers above (you could then code one wrapper in GTK for Gnome and another wrapper in Qt for KDE). You could even go even further by designing and developing a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) *library* implementing your features, leaving the bulk of the GUI work to other developers (and accepting improvements to your free software library)?

Comment: In addition, there are various projects that allow using the same theme on GTK+ and Qt, or even ports of the same themes to those differing theme specifications.

Comment: I was thinking on something "on top" QT/GTK/etc, independent from they, something that will be rendered by GTK on Gnome and will look native in them and when running on KDE it will be rendered by QT, etc. I think HTML is the only way to have UI looks the same on all DEs/platforms. Thanks Basile

Comment: @Bartosz: it would be nice to explain us what kind of application do you have in mind!

Comment: It was a generic question, I was thinking about general purpose apps, text editors, personal finance manager, etc.

Comment: It cannot be done, since Gnome & KDE look&feel guides are incompatible